# jquery tablesorter plugin sort just one way

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Hi have wrote tablesorter plugin to sort Polish chars but plugin sorts just one way
http://jsfiddle.net/Gk43v/ here is the example and plugin code

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
   id: 'polish-chars' ,
   type: 'text',
   is: function(s)
   {
       return false;
   },
   format: function(s)
   {
       return
       s.replace('\u0105'/g, 'a')
       .replace('\u0104'/g, 'A')
       .replace('\u0118'/g, 'E')
       .replace('\u0119'/g, 'e')
       .replace('\u0107'/g, 'c')
       .replace('\u0106'/g, 'C')
       .replace('\u0143'/g, 'N')
       .replace('\u0144'/g, 'n')
       .replace('Ó'/g, 'O')
       .replace('ó'/g, 'o')
       .replace('\u0141'/g, 'L')
       .replace('\u0142'/g, 'l')
       .replace('\u015a'/g, 'S')
       .replace('\u015b'/g, 's')
       .replace('\u0179'/g, 'Z')
       .replace('\u017a'/g, 'z')
       .replace('\u017b'/g, 'Z')
       .replace('\u017c'/g, 'z')
   }
});
```

Edit:
When using this plugin with tablesorter it didn't show an error `/g`, so it should look like

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
   id: 'polish-chars',
   type: 'text',
   is: function(s)
   {
       return false;
   },
   format: function(s)
   {
       return s.replace('ą', 'a')
               .replace('Ą', 'A')
               .replace('Ę', 'E')
               .replace('ę', 'e')
               .replace('ć', 'c')
               .replace('Ć', 'C')
               .replace('Ń', 'N')
               .replace('ń', 'n')
               .replace('Ó', 'O')
               .replace('ó', 'o')
               .replace('Ł', 'L')
               .replace('ł', 'l')
               .replace('Ś', 'S')
               .replace('ś', 's')
               .replace('Ź', 'Z')
               .replace('ź', 'z')
               .replace('Ż', 'Z')
               .replace('ż', 'z');
   }
});
```

and work just like I wanted to work.

Comment: please edit what you require it to do ? the problem

Comment: I want my plugin to sort both ways `asc` and `desc`, chceck 2 column in jsfiddle example

Answer (score 2):

When using replace with `/g`, don't use quotes ([updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Gk43v/1/)):

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: 'polish-chars',
    type: 'text',
    is: function(s) {
        return false;
    },
    format: function(s) {
       return s.replace(/\u0105/g, 'a')
       .replace(/\u0104/g, 'A')
       .replace(/\u0118/g, 'E')
       .replace(/\u0119/g, 'e')
       .replace(/\u0107/g, 'c')
       .replace(/\u0106/g, 'C')
       .replace(/\u0143/g, 'N')
       .replace(/\u0144/g, 'n')
       .replace(/Ó/g, 'O')
       .replace(/ó/g, 'o')
       .replace(/\u0141/g, 'L')
       .replace(/\u0142/g, 'l')
       .replace(/\u015a/g, 'S')
       .replace(/\u015b/g, 's')
       .replace(/\u0179/g, 'Z')
       .replace(/\u017a/g, 'z')
       .replace(/\u017b/g, 'Z')
       .replace(/\u017c/g, 'z');
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you could try out my fork of [tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/index.html) which does [character equivalents replacements](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-locale-sort.html) when the `sortLocaleCompare` option is `true`. Just add the missing Polish characters to the list:

```
$.extend( $.tablesorter.characterEquivalents, {
    "a" : "\u0105", // ą
    "A" : "\u0104", // Ą
    "c" : "\u0107", // ć
    "C" : "\u0106", // Ć
    "e" : "\u0119", // ę
    "E" : "\u0118", // Ę
    "l" : "\u0142", // ł
    "L" : "\u0141", // Ł
    "n" : "\u0144", // ń
    "N" : "\u0143", // Ń
    "o" : "\u00f3", // ó
    "O" : "\u00d3", // Ó
    "s" : "\u015b", // ś
    "S" : "\u015a", // Ś
    "z" : "\u017a\u017c", // źż
    "Z" : "\u0179\u017b" // ŹŻ
});
```

Comment: I have to say that is one great fork `+1` from me. Tommorow will look to it closer

Comment: http://pastebin.com/NyFmhiyE I wrote plugin for such datetime format `dd.mm.YYY H:i:s` if someone would like

Comment: I've also modified the `shortDate` parser to work with a modified `dateFormat` option to allow [multiple date formats](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-option-date-format.html) ;)